# Hibernation not working on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: hibernate

I am using Ubuntu 14.04. I am unable to hibernate my system with sudo pm-hibernate. The screen only flashes then it returns to desktop, nothing happens. I have a swap partition of 4GB my RAM size is 3GB. Even the hibernate tray option doesn't actually hibernate the system instead only sends the system to sleep. Kindly help.

Answer (score -1):

I used [this guide](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/04/enable-hibernate-ubuntu-14-04/) and it worked for me but on my laptop I had to use "uswsusp" [Ubuntu's Help Wiki Hibernate](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PowerManagement/Hibernate) and see if hitting Shift when sending to Standbye helps

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Although the links may be helpful, please refrain from making "links-only" answers. If you wish to increase the quality of your answer, provide steps from the links cited to address the question.